# Extract address from description with regex

Tags: regex, street-address

Im trying to extract an address (written in french) out of a listing using regex. 
here is the example:

"Don't wait, this home won't be on the market for long!
Pictures can be forwarded upon request.

123 de la street - city
345-555-1234 "

Imagine that whole thing is item.description. Here is a working set so far:

In "item.description", replace "^\d{1,4} des|de la|du [^,\s]+$" with "whatever"

and the address (123 de la street) will be correctly written over with whatever. BUT if I try to make it the only thing kept from the description, something like this (which dosent work):

In "item.description" replace "(.*)(^\d{1,4} des|de la|du [^,\s]+$)(.*)" with "$2"

What would be the best way to replace the whole description with just the address?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding * to the first and last token, plus watch out for ^$ signs! (They match start and end of the text.)

```
"^(.*)(\d{1,4} des|de la|du [^,\s]+)(.*)$"
```

Comment: Thanks Miroslav, I tried this as well with no luck. I would have assumed this to work though... have a look at the comment I left on David's answer to see if that changes anything

Comment: Since your text is spanning multiple lines, I would assume the problem is that "." doesn't match newline characters. I am not familiar with Yahoo Pipes, so I can't advice you on how to change this behaviour.

Comment: The multiline was the problem, I just removed all <br> tags before running this regex and it worked. Thank you!